# Буфер обмена максимум 2 символа

Tags: c, символы

Программа меняет строку записанную в текстовом документе, следующим образом ABCDEF на BADCFE

```
int main() 
{ 
char c[20]; 
char x; 
int length =18; 

FILE *fp; 
fp=fopen("1.txt","r"); 
fgets(c,20,fp); 
for(int i=0;i<length;i+=2) 
{ 
x=c[i]; 
c[i]=c[i+1]; 
c[i+1]=x; 
} 
fclose(fp); 

fp=fopen("1.txt","w"); 
fputs(c,fp); 
fclose(fp); 
}
```

НО надо чтобы буфер обмена содержал максимум 2 символа, а он содержит 20, когда меняю на 2, программа не работает

Comment: Вы про место для нуль-терминатора не забыли?

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса. Вы хотите по два символа считывать из файла?! Это мягко говоря бредовая идея даже для микроконтроллеров.

Answer (score 0):

```
// gcc splitlett.c -o splitlett
// ./splitlett
// cat 1.txt 2.txt
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { 
  int a ;
  int b ;
  FILE *fp1;
  FILE *fp2;  
  fp1 = fopen("1.txt","r"); 
  if  ( fp1 == NULL ) return ;
  fp2 = fopen("2.txt","w"); 
  if  ( fp2 == NULL ) return ;
  while ( 1 ) { 
    a = fgetc ( fp1 ) ;
    if ( a == EOF ) break ;
    b = fgetc ( fp1 ) ;
    if ( b == EOF ) break ;
    if ( fputc ( b , fp2 ) == EOF ) break ;
    if ( fputc ( a , fp2 ) == EOF ) break ; } 
  fclose(fp2); 
  fclose(fp1); }
```

По просьбам зрителей вариант второй : работа с файлом используя буфер два байта, и спрятал `while(1)`. Наверное будет чуть быстрее.

```
// gcc splitlett.c -o splitlett
// ./splitlett
// cat 1.txt 2.txt
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { 
  size_t freads ;
  char buf[2];
  char tmp;
  FILE *fp1;
  FILE *fp2;  
  fp1 = fopen("1.txt","r"); 
  if  ( fp1 == NULL ) return ;
  fp2 = fopen("2.txt","w"); 
  if  ( fp2 == NULL ) goto Close1 ;
  do { 
    freads = fread(buf, sizeof(char), 2U, fp1);
    if ( freads != 2U ) break ;
    tmp = buf[0] ;
    buf[0] = buf[1] ;
    buf[1] = tmp ;
    freads =  fwrite(buf, sizeof(char), 2U, fp2);
  }while(freads == 2U); 
  fclose(fp2); 
Close1 :  
  fclose(fp1); }
```

Comment: Бесконечный цикл, замена через прямой доступ к файлу на каждый символ... даже не знаю, что хуже.

Comment: Вариант второй думаете будет лучше?

Comment: Лучше. Теперь осталось выяснить, что же хотел топик стартер. Идея читать с таким маленьким буфером сама по себе ущербна.